# How add several attributes to elements at once?

Tags: php, domdocument

At the moment i have this code, but it is slow and not logical:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$hrefs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

$attributes = array('data-role' => 'button', 'data-inline' => 'true', 'data-mini' => 'true', 'data-transition' => 'slide');

foreach($hrefs as $href){
    foreach($attributes as $attribute_name => $attribute_value){
        $attribute = $dom->createAttribute($attribute_name);
        $attribute->value = $attribute_value;

        $href->appendChild($attribute);
    }
}
```

It also can be done with `str_replace('<a', '<a data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" data-transition="slide" ', $html);`, which is more faster (1.0E-5s < 0.22s), but i also producing replacements in certain links, so i need to have it as DOM.

Comment: consider using jquery for this instead of php?

Comment: What do you mean by not logical? You might want to write yourself a helper function or extend `DOMElement` providing the feature you're missing like adding data attributes via an array (you could also spare the `data-` prefix in all those keys and what not.